# Four numbers are chosen from 1 to 20. If $1\leq k \leq 17$, in how many ways is the difference between the smallest and the largest number equal to k?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Four numbers are chosen from 1 to 20. If $1\leq k \leq 17$, in how many ways is the difference between the smallest and the largest number equal to k?

**My Working:**

*Case 1:*
The greatest number is 20.

As $1\leq k \leq 17$, hence, the smallest number $\geq 3$.
If it is 3, the number of ways of choosing the other 2 numbers is $16\cdot 15$
Similarly, for smallest number $4, 5, 6,\cdots$ no. of possibilities are $15\cdot 14$, $14\cdot 13$, $13\cdot 12$,$\cdots$

Hence, total combinations$=\sum{n(n+1)}$ from $n=16$ to $n=1$

*Case 2:*
The greatest number is 19 and 18. We can proceed similarly to get the same result i.e. total combinations$=\sum{n(n+1)}$ from $n=16$ to $n=1$

*Case 3:*
The greatest number $\leq 17$.
Let us call it $l$. total combinations$=\sum{n(n+1)}$ from $n=l-2$ to $n=1$

**Problem:**
This solution is very long. Is there an easier way of solving it?

Comment: Can the numbers chosen repeat?  Does order of selection of the numbers matter?  In the case that numbers cannot repeat and order of selection doesn't matter, then you have a grave error in your calculation, you calculated as though the order of the middle two numbers did matter.  In the case that order *does* matter, you again have a major error as you do not account for this for all four of the numbers, only the middle two.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh yeah, forgot to divide by '2!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that numbers may not be repeated and that order of selection of the numbers does not matter., i.e. we are counting how many subsets, $A$, of $\{1,2,\dots,20\}$ have the property that $max(A)-min(A)=k$

First, recognize that $max(A)-1\geq max(A)-min(A)=k$ implies $max(A)\geq k+1$, for example if the distance between max and min is six, you cannot have the largest number be $6$ or less, it must be at least $7$ or more.

> **Step 1:** Pick the largest number.

We first need to count how many ways in which we may pick the largest number for our set for a specific $k$.  As $20\geq max(A)\geq k+1$ there are $20-k$ different possibilities for $max(A)$.

(*E.g. for $k=19$ our only choice is for $max(A)=20$ and $min(A)=1$ for a total of $20-19=1$ choices while for $k=17$ we could have $max(A)=18~min(A)=1,~~max(A)=19~min(A)=2,$ or $max(A)=20~min(A)=3$ for a total of $20-17=3$ choices*)

In having picked the largest number, the smallest number is forced to ensure that the desired difference is achieved.

> **Step 2:** Pick the locations of the remaining two numbers in relation to the smallest number.

There will be $k-1$ available numbers between $min(A)$ and $max(A)$ to choose from and we wish to select two of these without regard to their order.  There are $\binom{k-1}{2}$ ways to accomplish this.

There are then $(20-k)\binom{k-1}{2}$ subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,20\}$ with the property that $max(A)-min(A)=k$

Note: for $k=1$ and $k=2$ the above formula correctly gives a total of zero possibilities without need to add a special case since $\binom{k-1}{2}=0$ in both of those cases.

Comment: Thank you :) If you want you could just add a step three giving a summation for all 'k's (although it's pretty obvious)

Comment: @OsheenSachdev my understanding was that the question was being asked about a specific single arbitrary value of $k$ in that range., not asking the sum of the totals over all possible $k$ in the range.  If you were to sum the totals for each possible value of $k$ over the range $\{3,4,\dots,19\}$ you will wind up with a final total of $\binom{20}{4}$ as it is just a more complicated and longer way of partitioning the set of four-element subsets (*which yields a derivation of an interesting identity at least, but otherwise seems unuseful*)

Comment: "you will wind up with a final total of $\binom{20}{4}$ as it is just a more complicated and longer way of partitioning the set of four-element subsets" How? This seems interesting...

Comment: I hope you have noticed that $k\leq 17$

Comment: @OsheenSachdev yes I did, which is why I specified in my aside comment that it was to do with if $k$ ranged all the way up to $19$ instead.  Why they would be equal is because of the first principle of combinatorics, if two expressions correctly count the same scenario (*albeit looking different and arrived at via different methods*) then they must be equal.

Comment: No, I get that but I wanted to understand how they count the same scenario...

Comment: @OsheenSachdev $\binom{20}{4}$ is the number of four-element subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,20\}$.  Counted a different way, it is #with largest difference 3 + #with largest difference 4 + #with largest difference 5 + ... + #with largest difference 19.  As each of those in the summation count a different non-overlapping scenario, and each 4-element subset falls into one of those categories, every four-element subset is accounted for and accounted for only once (i.e. it partitions it), hence it counts the same thing.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you were talking about $k\leq 17$